# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) ERROR when adding DATA

Tags: python, json, django, string

Right now I'm trying to get user-specific data in a website I'm using but I'm getting what seems to be a pretty basic error when I click submit on one of my forms.
The error is:
****str** returned non-string (type NoneType)**

my view looks like this:

```
def adddata_asbestos(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    form = SheetForm_Asbestos(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()

        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/front_page/sheets/list_data_asbestos/")

    context = {"form": form,}

    return render(request, 'sheets/add_data/add_data_asbestos.html', context)
```

And importantly this is the form that adds data:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/add_data.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/materialize2.css" %}">

    <title>Ladder - Asbestos Add Data</title>
</head>
<div class="back_button_sheet">
    <a style="background-color: #2f3d50; border-radius: 18px;" href="{% url 'list_asbestos' %}" class="btn btn-primary">< Back</a>
</div>

    <div class="table_position_add container my-4">
        <div class="card my-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">Asbestos Testing</h4>
                <form class="table_add" method="POST" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Date</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"{{ form.date }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.date.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Time</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="HH:MM am/pm"{{ form.time }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.time.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sample Date</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"{{ form.sample_date }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.sample_date.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sample Time</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="HH:MM am/pm"{{ form.sample_time }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.sample_time.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Occupancy</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.occupancy }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.occupancy.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Building and Address</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.building_address }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.building_address.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Area / Room</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.room }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.room.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Location in</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.location }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.location.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sample #</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.sample_number }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.sample_number.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sample Type</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.sample_type }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.sample_type.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sample of</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.sample_of }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.sample_of.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Asbestos Notes</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.asbestos_notes }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.asbestos_notes.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Inspector</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.inspector }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.inspector.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Trans By</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.trans_by }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.trans_by.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Trans Date</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"{{ form.trans_date }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.trans_date.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Sample Company</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.sample_company }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.sample_company.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Analysis Priority Days</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.analysis_priority }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.analysis_priority.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Positive / Negative</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.pos_neg }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.pos_neg.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Percentage %</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.percentage }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.percentage.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Type of Asbestos</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.type }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.type.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Date Examined</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"{{ form.date_examined }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.date_examined.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">ACT #'s</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.atc }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.atc.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Square of Linear Footage</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.square_linear }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.square_linear.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Scope of Work</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.scope_work }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.scope_work.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Cost per SF / LF</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.cost_per }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.cost_per.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">PCB - Tested</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.pcb_tested }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.pcb_tested.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Cost</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.cost }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.cost.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Approval Date</td>
                            <td>
                                <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"{{ form.date_approval }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.date_approval.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">ATC Invoice #</td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.atc_invoice }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.atc_invoice.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold;">Inspector's Note<h6>(Wont show up in data table)</h6></td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.notes }}
                                <div style="font-size: 15px;">{{ form.notes.errors }}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input style="background-color: #2f3d50; border-radius: 18px;" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Submitting...'; this.form.submit();" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<be>
```

If anyone has a good source to have user-specific data with (form.ModelForm) that would be great as well.

EDIT:
This is also the full traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/my_app/sheet_asbestos/add/

Django Version: 3.1.2
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'my_app',
  'django_quill',
  'tinymce',
  'ckeditor',
  'storages',
  'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
    **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 614, in wrapper
        return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in 
    _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1653, in add_view
        return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, 
    extra_context)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site- 
   packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
          File 
    "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site-    packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site-    packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
        return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url,     extra_context)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site-    
    packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1584, in _changeform_view
        self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message)
      File "C:\Users\herte_x6izw1s\anaconda3\envs\inspect_list\lib\site-        
    packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 814, in log_addition
        object_repr=str(object),

    Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/my_app/sheet_asbestos/add/
    Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Comment: @William Van Onsem  The full traceback has been added